# header and footer in scrbook

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2, scrbook

I am having a problem with the scrbook class. Since I am quite new to it I spent quite some time researching but somehow haven't found a way to resolve it.
I am trying to write a LaTeX document for uni and would like to have headers and footers on each page.
The essential lines in my document are as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper,fleqn,ngerman]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm, includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}

\deftripstyle{pagestyle}[0.5pt][0.3pt]{\pagemark}{}{\titleinfo}{\pagemark}{\today}{\authorinfo}
\pagestyle{pagestyle}


\newcommand{\titleinfo}{Model}
\newcommand{\authorinfo}{D. Wright}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\end{document}
```

Somehow it doesn't seem to work. I get the following output:
[image: test file]

When I change the `\documentclass` to `article` or `scrartcl` I do get the headers and footers on each page but not in `book`, or `scrbook` (which would be the one that I would like to work with). Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in section 3.12 of the KoMaScript manual, chapter starting pages use the `\chapterstyle` page style and the default meaning of `\chapterstyle` is `plain`. Just renew the meaning:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
  left=1cm,
  right=1cm,
  top=1cm,
  bottom=1cm,
  includeheadfoot
]{geometry}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\deftripstyle{pagestyle}
  [0.5pt]
  [0.3pt]
  {\pagemark}
  {}
  {\titleinfo}
  {\pagemark}
  {\today}
  {\authorinfo}

\pagestyle{pagestyle}
% use "pagestyle" also on chapter starting pages
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{pagestyle}


\newcommand{\titleinfo}{Model}
\newcommand{\authorinfo}{D. Wright}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\kant
\end{document}
```

(The `kantlipsum` package is just for providing mock text.)

[image]